# How best to create custom styled components in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

seemingly simple problem:

1. **Example Background:** we have many lists of items and render them in the UI with `<List>`.
2. **Example Problem:** we *usually* (but not always) want to remove the extra padding that is injected on `<List>` (ex: `<UnpaddedList>`).

As another example, perhaps we want to have most lists be collapsible by default with a `<List onClick={...}>` trigger to become `<CollapsableList>`.  For most examples below, the unpadded is sufficient to illustrate.

On first guess, I'd expect something like `CustomList extends List` ([but see Facebook inheritance advice](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance)). There are many ways to do it, but what are the advantages/disadvantages...they seem to conflict:

## `createStyled()`

This is intended to entirely replace the theme... in times intended to break brand standards.  Although we could go back and merge the existing theme, this seems against the purpose of this tool, and `deepmerge` perhaps could slow performance? this would work well if it could inherit the current theme context.  perhaps lots of extra component names is bad practice?  ex: `List`, `UnpaddedList` `UnpaddedLargeList`, `UnpaddedLargeGreenList`, etc.

see https://mui.com/system/styled/#create-custom-styled-utility

## `createTheme()`

this allows total override of styles and props for each component.  The only issue is that it may not be clear why a component is styled a certain way and keeps its name. (ex: `<List>` isn't renamed to `<UnpaddedList>`)This could be confusing if you have a component that is inheriting a theme from a parent component somewhere up in the tree and appears with an unexpected style.  the developer would have to trace each parent component to find where the theme was injected with `<ThemeProvider>`.  But perhaps such injecting sub-themes in unexpected ways would be its own anti-pattern.

Also, without clear docs/typescript, it took a lot of reading to determine how best to pass and modify the current theme:

```js
function extendThemeWithGreen(theme: Theme) {
  let themeOptions: ThemeOptions = { palette: { primary: { main: "green" } } };
  return createTheme(theme, themeOptions);
}

function Example() {
  return <ThemeProvider theme={extendThemeWithGreen}> example</ThemeProvider>;
}
```

another issue is that [some components have arbitrary white-space injected](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3f58dd9208c5aa8daed74c74d97cd63c2c35a785/packages/mui-material/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L79-L88) into them. this is not documented and has no type-hinting.  the only way to discover those is to hunt down the source code.  from there you would likely have to create another set of styles that override the native styles and introduce bloat into the app.

see https://mui.com/system/styled/#custom-components
see https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#2-reusable-style-overrides

## `return <List {...props} />`

Wrapping components would be nice.  (ex: `const UnpaddedList = (props) => <List disablePadding {...props} />;`)
so far this has been a lot of trouble.  for example, should the props be `ListProps` or `OverridableComponent<ListTypeMap<{}, "ul">>`? Or suppose both the end component and wrapped component have `sx`... do I have to set a `deepMerge` to deal with duplicate props.  Maybe I just need to spend more time to get it going?

see https://mui.com/guides/composition/#wrapping-components

## `sx={...}` or `style={...}` or `class=...`

these props generally allow customization, however they are effectively one-off.  ex: you have to `<List style={{padding:0}} />` also, this loses type safety **(expect things to break in the future)** `class` can be separate, but still hard to retain type safety.  Legacy `makeStyles(` is similar

see https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/
see https://mui.com/styles/api/#createstyles-styles-styles

## `<UnstyledList component={...}`

This is largely an upcoming feature and not fully implemented yet.  Although this could avoid future css conflicts, it still doesn't facilitate `props` override (or if it does... it isn't clear from the docs)

see https://mui.com/customization/unstyled-components/#main-content

## `<Box component={List} ... />`

Use the `Box` wrapper to create a custom component.  The docs aren't entirely clear on this.  It may be something like:

```js
function UnpaddedList(props: ListProps){
  return <Box component={List} disablePadding {...props} />
}
```

Many of the component props have generic modifiers... however it isn't clear how this new component would be written to match (or extend) the original component props

see https://mui.com/system/box/#overriding-mui-components

## `variant="unpadded"`

this is close, however it appears to create a typing issue, or special treatment to import.  i could see this causing confusion down the road, but at least linting would throw a warning if not implemented properly.  it doesn't have a good way to do composition (ex: `variant="unpadded&collapsible"`).  it also isn't clear how this is done for components that do not have variants built in.

see https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#adding-new-component-variants

## `props`

of course some, but not all, can be done through props keep type safety.  (ex: `<List disablePadding={true}>`) however this [isn't DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  it is overall worse to manage (no brand standard). it also makes the code much more difficult read and excessively verbose

## other methods?

perhaps I missed another way. I also can't find any graceful solution to the [hardcoded whitespace](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3f58dd9208c5aa8daed74c74d97cd63c2c35a785/packages/mui-material/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L79-L88) in MUI components

Answer (score 1):

If you have a component that is used in multiple places and only one of them needs to have some special styles or you need to tweak or fix an edge case in a specific layout, use `sx` prop. It's suitable for one-off styles like this:

```
<List sx={{ p: 0 }}>
```

If you need to apply some styles occasionally in a component, use `styled`. For example if a component is used in 100 places but only in 20 places it needs to have the padding disabled then add a padding prop to enable the styles in the rarer case:

```
const options = {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'disablePadding',
};
const List = styled(
  MuiList,
  options,
)(({ theme, disablePadding = false }) => ({
  ...(disablePadding && {
    padding: 0,
  }),
}));
```

```
// I dont always use disablePadding but sometimes I need it
<List disablePadding>
```

Comment: I really like your suggested approach with `styled(...` and `shouldForwardProp`.  I'll give it a try.  Somehow I overlooked the `styled(...` even after hours looking and even though I did see the `createStyled(...`. I'll mark as answer once I have a moment to test it out.  Thank you!

For anyone else looking, here's the link:

https://mui.com/system/styled/#styled-component-options-styles-component

Comment: In my initial test, this appears to only affect styling (can't affect functionality).  so, for example, if i wanted to do `<List maxItems={10}>`, it would be nice to be able to receive the props, then have something like `children = children.slice(0,10)` before passing the children to the standard `List` component.  unfortunately, the `styled` approach appears unable to do this

Comment: @bristweb `styled` is only used to create stylesheet (CSS). `children.slice(0,10)` is JS code to remove certain items. That specific example of yours is about component logic rather than styles so you can't use `styled` for that task. You can create a wrapper component of `MuiList` and remove extra children easily as an alternative.